# OpenSSH client sends environment variable it should not

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

I have a host that doesn't have the termcap entries for non-standard terminals and I cannot add them (policy).

I use tmux which sets a terminal type to something that this device does not recognise. No issue here, worst case I can set the TERM to 'xterm' and be done with it. But:

I've configured some defaults for the OpenSSH client, among other settings, I instructed it to not send any environment variables other than LANG and LC_*.

The relevant part of ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
  SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

My OpenSSH client version is 6.6.1.

Here's the transcript of my SSH session with irrelevant lines removed:

```
% TERM=you.shall.not.pass ssh -vvv host
...
debug1: Connection established.
...
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
...
debug1: Sending environment.
...
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
...
debug3: Ignored env TERM
```

As per the above, it sent LANG, wrote it ignored TERM but yet somehow it has propagated to the remote host:

```
root@host% echo $TERM
you.shall.not.pass
```

Is this something you've come across? It's not a major issue but I thought that unless I'm doing something wrong, this is inconsistent with the documentation.

Comment: this can help you http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67537/prevent-ssh-client-passing-term-environment-variable-to-server

Comment: Thank you - I've found some interesting info in the thread you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ssh doesn't pass the value of TERM as an environment variable per se. The SSH protocol message for requesting a pseudo-terminal (PTY) has a field for the terminal type, along with things like the terminal's width and height. See [RFC 4254, Section 6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#page-11).

Try running a command without a PTY, and you'll probably get different results, for example:

```
$ TERM=foo ssh localhost 'echo $TERM'
dumb
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link to the RFC - this makes sense now.